# Rails rescue redirect_to and show alert instead of error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have an action in my controller that makes a call to a 3rd party API.  I want to catch any exception that may be raised when contacting this API and just redirect back to a page and show an error message.  When using rescue => e I just continue to get the normal Rails 500 error page instead of getting redirected with the flash message.

```
begin
  jira_post("issue/#{@incident.ticket_number}/comment", comment)
  format.html { redirect_to incident_url, notice: "Ticket #{@incident.ticket_number} updated." }
  format.json { head :no_content }
rescue => e
  format.html { redirect_to incident_url, alert: "Error connecting to JIRA API!" }
end
```

Instead of getting redirected I still get an error page saying:

```
SocketError in IncidentsController#show
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

What am I doing wrong experts of Stackoverflow?

Comment: In which line are you getting this? Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Gah the page I was redirecting to had another API call that was failing but not being rescued.  That will teach me not to follow the trace, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The page I was redirecting to had another API call in the action that was failing and not being rescue'd which was generating the error page.  Thanks to Agis for reminding me to follow the stacktrace...